# macOS AppleScript no longer working with image insert into Microsoft Word Document in Big Sur

Tags: applescript, ms-office

I have been running this script to insert an image into a Word document table cell. It had been working well until I upgraded macOS to Big Sur. When I run the script, I now get the following error:

> error "Microsoft Word got an error: The object you are trying to access does not exist" number -1728 from text object of cell 1 of row 1 of table 1 of active document

This is the script:

```
set ScaledReportImages to "Macintosh HD:Users:raft:Library:Group Containers:UBF8T346G9.Office:Temp:picture.jpg"

tell application "Microsoft Word"
    tell active document
        set x to text object of cell 1 of row 1 of table 1
        make new inline picture at before x with properties {file name:ScaledReportImages as text, save with document:true}
    end tell
end tell

tell application "Microsoft Word"
    set content of text object of (cell 1 of row 2 of table 1 of active document) to "Text Here"
end tell
```

One other thing is that I am running this on the new 13 inch MBP running the M1 processor. It appears that any script that tries to interface with Word fails. I would really appreciate anyone's insight into this as it is driving me crazy!

Comment: Hi Spiro, I see you've edited the title to remove ‘Microsoft Word’ — are you having trouble with AppleScript telling other applications? The AppleScript you provided only communicated with Word and I'm not having any difficulties with AppleScript in general on Big Sur.

Comment: Hi, the issue is when running that applescript as documented it gives the error as per my post. When I run the exact same script on Catalina it works without issue so I assumed it was a Big Sur issue. I have not updated or changed microsoft word so didn't think that was the issue. Are you able to test on your system? All you need to do is create a word document, add a table 4 columns x 2 rows and try run the script to insert a picture into one of the cells. thanks for your help.

Comment: Applescript works but this particular script has stopped working with the upgrade. I have corrected the title to better reflect this